# Change vuetify default font color in theme

Tags: css, vuetify.js

How can I change Vuetify's default font color for light and dark theme?

I already have custom themes (see below), but can't find in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing) how to change the default css for text.

I see code is generated in [`variables/settings/_light.scss`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/0c90436cb9d5627898c103c0b4830eec3f4c82f9/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_light.scss), but not sure how to modify it.

I want to avoid adding CSS like this with `!important`:

```css
.theme--light.v-application {
  color: #4a4a4a !important;
}
```

```json
theme: {
      options: {
        customProperties: true,
        variations: false,
      },
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: colors.blue.base,
          secondary: colors.grey.base,
          anchor: color.blue.base,
        },
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.base,
          secondary: colors.grey.base,
          anchor: color.blue.base,
        },
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify does not set the default font color, the theme colors it does provide are optional and must be applied to elements using specific classnames, e.g.

```html
<p class="primary--text">text</p>
```

The above will apply the `primary` color code to that one paragraph element.

One thing you can try is [creating your own theme variable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/vuetify/#sass) but you'd still have to apply it at your application's root component level

```scss
// src/sass/variables.scss

// Globals
$material-light: (
  'text': (
    'default': #4a4a4a
  )
);
```

```scss
// App.vue

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/scss/variables.scss";
#app {
  color: map-get($material-light, "text", "default");
}
</style>
```